# While using object.innerHTML or $object.append when creating a div tag with an onclick event it won't allow me to pass variables too it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I'm creating a chat application where when a message is received the user can click on the message and see information about it, the application works and there are no errors in any other part of the code however, when I add the message to the chat div element (in it's own div), although the message shows with the variables passed in correctly (usernames, color of text and message) when I add the onclick element it won't display the information.

I have tried two possible methods:

Using jquery and appending:

```
    $chat.append("<div id =\'"+user+"\' style=\'color:"+color+";\' onclick='alert("+user+")'>"+user+ ": " + msg + "<br/></div>");
```

Using innerHTML:

```
    var content = chat.innerHTML;
    chat.innerHTML = content + "<div id=\'"+user+"\' style=\'color:"+color+";\' onclick='alert("+user+")'>"+user+ ": "+msg+"<br/><div>";
```

As said, everything else works fine but the onclick function does not work and displays an alert box but with no information just "[object HTMLcollection]".

Comment: We can't help you without a more complete example of your code. All I can see from what you've given is that `user` is not a string - it's an array of HTML elements. If you used `console.log()` instead of `alert() you'd be able to see exactly what it contains.

Comment: It might be easier to just use `addEventListener`.

Comment: what is `chat` or `$chat` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have something strange with quotes. Try this:

```
$('.chat').append('<div id =' + user + ' style=color:' + color + ';onclick=alert("' + user + '")>' + user + ': ' + msg + '<br/></div>');
```

EDIT: You don't need to add extra quotes for id value or style value but need to add it for alert argument instead.